# Gun shooting repeatedly in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

I've been trying to find a tutorial for how to animate bullets firing successively (including shells ejecting) but all the tutorials seem to be in the game engine.  Is there a way to do this in cycles?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Your best bet is to start by creating an animation for firing once.

Then for things like the muzzle flash you can loop that animation (either using multiple strips in the NLA, or a cycles modifier on the fcurves of its animation).

For the bullets, you probably want multiple objects in case multiple bullets are in-camera.  They can share an animation that is shifted in time using NLA strips.

The casings will be similar to the bullet: having multiple objects that share an animation using NLA strips displaced in time.

(edit:)

Keyframing the `hide_render` property (the camera icon in the outliner) is a popular technique for making something appear/disappear (bullets, shell casings, although you could also conceal them inside the gun's polygons where the camera can't see them)

Comment: Thanks!  But how would you make animations for multiple objects (i.e. bullets)?  Would it be hiding several duplicates and keyframing their animations and appearances?  Sorry I'm pretty new to animation and have never used the NLA editor.

Comment: Yeah, the NLA editor can confuse first-time users.  I wrote https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WrrdFpZ-VC7taxu4iD3hZIowYvyM953iZpBwkZ78PgA/edit , but you probably want to find a google video that explains the basics first.